# Django rest query

Tags: sql, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Excuse me, how can I navigate in a list in django with% s, since with a single value it works fine for me, but I want to pass two parameters to my query.

```
class PruebaSQL(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CountSerealizer

    def get_queryset(self):
        num = self.kwargs['num']
        date = self.kwargs['date'] 
        result = (num, date)
        queryset = Sale.objects.raw("SELECT 1 id, id_customer_id, count(DISTINCT id_customer_id) FROM sales_sale where datesale > %s group by id_customer_id having count(id_customer_id) >  %s", [result])
        return queryset
```

How can I put the positions? or there is another way to pass the data

Comment: You really shouldn't expose a raw query parameter via a query string. Django's documentation on Raw Queries is fairly clear on this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note `[result]` is identical to `[(num, date)]`, which is a list containing one element (a tuple). Try passing `result` on its own, without putting it in a list - `(num, date)` already contains the two elements you need:

```
queryset = Sale.objects.raw("SELECT 1 id, id_customer_id, count(DISTINCT id_customer_id) FROM sales_sale where datesale > %s group by id_customer_id having count(id_customer_id) >  %s", result)
```